# Tao's proof of Szemeredi-Trotter theorem on incidences

Tags: combinatorics

In Tao's proof of Szemeredi-Trotter theorem on Point-Line incidences , he uses a lemma which decomposes the real plane into cells. During the proof of this lemma, the final step of getting rid of the logarithmic factor involves a induction on the "Bad cells" which violate the bound. My question is if we use the statement of the lemma as the induction hypothesis, then we apply this to the bad cells. Now what happens to the partition that actually resulted in these bad cells?

http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/the-szemeredi-trotter-theorem-and-the-cell-decomposition/#cell